# Pig Latin distinguishing Map or Reduce queries

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have the following data sample:

```
AGE,EDU,SEX,SALARY
67,10th,Male,<=50K
17,10th,Female,<=50K
40,Assoc-voc,Male,>50K
35,Assoc-voc,Male,<=50K
57,Assoc-voc,Male,<=50K
49,Assoc-voc,Male,>50K
42,Bachelors,Male,>50K
30,Bachelors,Male,>50K
23,Bachelors,Female,<=50K
```

==============================================

I created the following Pig Latin/hadoop script:

```
sensitive = LOAD '/mdsba' using PigStorage(',') as (AGE,EDU,SEX,SALARY);
    *--Filtered the data by the salary
    Data_filter1 = FILTER sensitive by (SALARY matches '<=50K');
    Data_filter2 = FILTER sensitive by (SALARY matches '>50K');
    --group both filters
    B= foreach(group Data_filter1 by(AGE,EDU,SEX)) 
    generate Data_filter1;
    C= foreach(group Data_filter2 by(AGE,EDU,SEX)) 
    generate Data_filter2;
    Dump B ;
    Dump C ;
```

=============================================================

Is there any way to determine whether the queries B,C, Data_filter1, or Data_filter2 run on Map or Reduce process. Since the following report is generated at the end of the job:

```
Elapsed: 35sec  
Diagnostics: 
 Average Map Time: 12sec  
 Average Shuffle Time: 10sec  
 Average Merge Time: 0sec  
 Average Reduce Time: 2sec
```

With many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you are launching the job you'll see a string

```
 org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: Alias1[73,14] C: Alias2[20, 9] R: Alias3[90, 78]
```

M stands for mapper, C for combiner, R for reducer. But in general case there is a possibility that your queries will run on both mapper and reducer